# The preliminary of the Bandit Gradient Algorithm

Tags: greedy-algorithms, gradient-descent

In the papers introducing **The Bandit Gradient Algorithm as Stochastic Gradient Ascent**, the following relationship:

[image]

is always considered as a preliminary and lacks proof for it. Does anyone know how does this relationship come about?
($\pi_t(x)$ is the probability of choosing action $x$ at time $t$ and $q_*(x)$ is the mean reward for action $x$)

Comment: What is $q_*$ in this context? Is it the average reward of action $x$?

Comment: @nir shahar Yes, it is the mean reward for action x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows almost immediately from the definition of [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value), when we sample the actions with the distribution that $\pi_t$ (the bandit) defines, and the inherent randomness of the model.

First, let us make sure we use the same terminology:

- $\pi_t(x)$ is the probability that the bandit chose action $x\in\text{Actions}$
- $R(x,r)$ will be the probability we got reward $r\in [0,R_{max}]$, when we play action $x\in \text{Actions}$
- $q_*(x)$ will be $\mathbb{E}_{~r\text{~} R(x,\cdot)}[r]$, which is exactly the average reward when you play action $x$.

Now, notice that $$\mathbb{E}[R_t]=\mathbb{E}_{~x\text{~} \pi_t(\cdot),~r\text{~}R(x,\cdot)}[r]=\mathbb{E}_{x\text{~}\pi_t(\cdot)}[q_*(x)]$$
This is true, since by definition $R_t$ is sampled by choosing an action $x$ using $\pi_t$, and then receiving a random reward that depends on the action $x$ we chose. Do note though, that the second equality is derived by substituting our definition of $q_*(x)$ into the expectation.

Now, $$\mathbb{E}[R_t]=\\\mathbb{E}_{x\text{~}\pi_t(\cdot)}[q_*(x)]=\\\sum_{x\in\text{Actions}} \pi_t(x)\cdot q_*(x)$$

The last equality is the definition of expectation. Hence, $\mathbb{E}[R_t]=\sum_{x}\pi_t(x)\cdot q_*(x)$ as we wanted to show.